# Constant Coefficient Chini equation

Tags: differential-equations

The general form of a Chini differential equation is
\begin{equation}
y^\prime(x) = r(x) + p(x) y(x) + q(x) y(x)^n\quad \mbox{with } n \neq \{0,1\} 
\end{equation}
which generalises of the basic Bernoulli, Riccati and Abel equations. I'm interested in solving the special and most basic case with constant coefficients
\begin{equation}
y^\prime(x) = r + p y(x) + q y(x)^n\quad  
\end{equation}
So first I check $p, r \neq 0\ \&\ q = 0$ which is a first order linear non-homogeneous DE and obtain

```
solution = DSolve[{y'[x] + y[x]*p == r}, y[x], x];
A[x_] = Simplify[y[x] /. solution[[1]]];
A[x]
```

\begin{equation}
c_1 e^{-p x}+\frac{r}{p}
\end{equation}

Then I check $p , q\ \neq 0\ \&\ r = 0$ which is a Bernoulli DE.

```
solution = DSolve[{y'[x] + y[x]*p == q*y[x]^n}, y[x], x];
A[x_] = Simplify[y[x] /. solution[[1]]];
A[x]
```

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{q-e^{(n-1) p (x-c_1)}}{p}\right){}^{\frac{1}{1-n}}
\end{equation}

Then finally a solution `just' needs to deal with the constant. So I check $p , q, r \neq 0$

```
solution = DSolve[{y'[x] + y[x]*p == q*y[x]^n + r}, y[x], x];
A[x_] = Simplify[y[x] /. solution[[1]]];
A[x]
```

\begin{equation}
\text{InverseFunction}\left[\int _1^{\text{$\#$1}}\frac{1}{q K[1]^n-p K[1]+r}dK[1]\&\right][c_1+x]
\end{equation}

So apparently M tries direct integration but unsurprisingly cannot do it ? Is this true with more information ?

```
g[y_] := 1/(r - p*y + q*y^n);
Integrate[g[y], {y, y0, y1}, Assumptions -> {r > 0, p > 0, q > 0}, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]
```

\begin{equation}
\text{Integrate}\left[\frac{1}{q y^n-p y+r},\{y,\text{y0},\text{y1}\},\text{Assumptions}\to \{r>0,p>0,q>0\},\text{Assumptions}\to n\in \mathbb{Z}\right]
\end{equation}
Yes.

Question: Although I haven't managed to solve this by hand yet, I think the DE should be solvable since the coefficients are invariant to $x$. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: The integration is respect to $y$ in the inverse function and the integral inverse limits are ambiguous as the correct form should be $$\int_{y_0}^y \frac{dy}{qy^n+r-py}=\int_{x_0}^x dx$$

Comment: That was a typo. Post edited.

Comment: This post is relevant https://mathoverflow.net/a/41181/41145

Comment: Yes the Chini coefficient is independent of x so a solution should be available.